# Eclipse For Android - Troubleshooting Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to android development and would like to ask for some advice regarding an 
      issue with debugging my android device to test with eclipse. Can anyone suggest a 
      user friendly step by step resource that will enable me to create a virtual device
      that is compatible with Android 4.0 and above since I am having problems with trying
      to create one. In summary:

```
  (1) How do I setup device debugging and code testing on an android device, specifically
      a Samsung Galaxy s4? Also running on a Windows 8 Operating System if helpful.

  (2) How do I create a virtual device that is compatible with Android 4.0 *KitKat on 
      eclipse? what device should I choose? What target should I choose?

   I will be grateful for any suggestions provided
```

Answer (score 0):

I Will try answer you questions :)

1) First, you need install you device driver,. Install Kies or Samsung USB Drivers :).
   Second, you will need a IDE for start code and debug this code, i recommend eclipse ADT.
   Link: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

With eclipse ADT, you can create a Virtual devices :)

2) You can't create a android device 4.0 compatible with Kit Kat, the Kit kat version it's 4.4, but you can work wit 4.4 and 4.0 at the same time, you just have to set the minimum api level 14 and the target 20.

English isn't my native language, sorry for any grammar errors.

Good Luck!